# gtkmm treeview set_activate_on_single_click does not compile

Tags: c++, treeview, gtkmm

Iam currently developping a unix application in c++ using gtkmm as my gui package. In this gui there is a nice treeview.

I want to set the activation of the rows in the treeview only on double click. There is a function for that called:

```
set_activate_on_single_click(bool)
```

However, if I want to call this function like so:

```
Gtk::TreeView *treeview = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::TreeView);
treeview->set_activate_on_single_click(false);
```

The code does not compile. I get an error like this:

```
error: ‘class Gtk::TreeView’ has no member named ‘set_activate_on_single_click’
```

It seems like SOME of the treeview's methods can get called, but others cannot. Does anyone have an idea why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was using gtkmm 3.4 instead of gtkmm 3.8. Those small details can be pretty nagging